# Question about how auto.arima works

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a time series that grows by 10% every month; I have done `auto.arima` on the month-over-month growth rate and absolute monthly numbers; for example

- Absolute numbers = 100, 110, 121, 133.1, ...
- Month-on-month-growth = 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ...

When I `auto.arima` on the growth rate as expected it gives me a forecast of the next month to be another 0.1, but when I do it on absolute numbers I get a implied growth of 0.0909.

Can someone please explain why there is a difference?

```
library(forecast)
rates = ts(rep(0.1,48), frequency = 12, start = c(1959, 1))
auto.arima(rates)
f  = auto.arima(rates)
print(forecast(f, 1))

foo = 1:48 ;
base = 1;


for ( i in 1:48 ) {
        foo[i] = base;
        base = base * 1.1;
}

levels = ts(foo,frequency = 12, start = c(1959,1))
fl = auto.arima(levels)
print(forecast(fl,1))
```

Comment: What is the form of the model that the software picked?  Was it the same ib both cases?

Answer (score 2):

Your first series is generated exactly by a (degenerate) ARIMA process: it's ARIMA(0,0,0), with a non-zero mean (0.1), and zero variance. `auto.arima` is able to find this model correctly, and since it is degenerate it can easily forecast the next values exactly.

Your second series is *not* generated by a nice (stable) ARIMA process (it's a degenerate AR(1) with $\phi > 1$). `auto.arima` will try to find the best model (according to AICc) within the universe of nice ARIMA models, but will not be able to find one that fits it exactly (it settles on ARIMA(0,2,0) with no mean).

You *can* fit your second series into the ARIMA framework by using a transformation, specifically a log-transform, such as by setting `lambda = 0` in the call to `auto.arima` (`auto.arima` does not try to set `lambda` automatically for you). In that case, it will find ARIMA(0,1,0) as the best model, but without drift, which your series does have. The reason for this is presumably because including the drift throws an error (`system is exactly singular`), which is caused by the fact that the "data" you are using isn't really data and does not contain any variability at all.